# Is there a way to avoid elimination deleting record that is foreign key on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to avoid elimination deleting records that are foreign key in another tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table containing the foreign key is called the referencing or child table, and the table containing the candidate key is called the referenced or parent table.

Use following foreign key options(On Delete and On Update) according to your need :

**Set NULL** : Sets the column value to NULL when you delete the parent table row.

**CASCADE** : CASCADE will propagate the change when the parent changes. If you delete a row, rows in constrained tables that reference that row will also be deleted, etc.

**RESTRICT** : RESTRICT causes you can not delete a given parent row if a child row exists that references the value for that parent row.

**NO ACTION** : NO ACTION and RESTRICT are very much alike. when an UPDATE or DELETE statement is executed on the referenced table, the DBMS verifies at the end of the statement execution that none of the referential relationships are violated. in short child row no concern if parent row delete or update.

And I think **RESTRICT** will fulfill your need.

Comment: Thank you but i want to determinate deleting row from parent table when has record in child.

Comment: You mean, you want to delete record from parent table even there is record present in child table. RIGHT?

Comment: I want way to check if the record i want delete it from parent table has not records depended with it in child table, deleting it. but if it has records in child table depended with it dont delete it.

Comment: So thats what restrict clause means. Just alter your table and specify on update and on delete options in key column as RESTRICTED.